# overloading operator ()

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, function-object

I have this declaration

```
struct Z {
    void operator ()( int a ) {
        cout << "operator()() " << a << endl;
    }
};

Z oz, *zp = &oz;

oz(1); //ok
(*zp)(2); //ok
zp(3); //"error: 'zp' cannot be used as a function"
```

Is there a way to modify struct declaration, so a call to No. 3 would succeed?

Comment: I do not think this is possible, I am fairly sure you cannot overload pointers to your type. You could however write a wrapper class around your pointers that does allow this syntax.

Comment: If some thought was put into it, I'm sure some guru could come up with a way using the preprocessor to achieve your goal.  But I sure hope that person wouldn't waste their time, since what you ask for is completely useless, and of no benefit to anyone, including you.

Comment: @benjamin-lindley you are right, that was a point...

Comment: Not that exact syntax, but you could add things so that `zp->call(3)` and/or `call(zp, 3)` work.

Comment: Note that you overloaded `operator()` not `operator()()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's expected behavior. `zp` is a pointer (a `Z *`), and `operator()` is overloaded for `Z`, not `Z *`. When you deference the pointer with `*zp`, you get a `Z &`, for which `operator()` *is* overloaded.

Unfortunately, you can't overload an operator for a pointer type (I think it has something to do with the fact that pointers are not user-defined types, but I don't have the Standard in front of me). You could simplify the syntax with references:

```
Z & r = *zp;
r(3);
```

Comment: no :) you destroyed the whole meaning of it with the last edit

Comment: your last edit introduced an irrelevant addition, something that was not intended to be used in the first place.

Comment: Would you kindly tell me what irrelevant addition?

Comment: the addition reference variable, it's already used as a call Nr.2

Comment: @Ulterior Yeah, but notice how I say "You could simplify the syntax".

Answer (score 0):

Provided your `Z` type has no state you can change it into a function.

```
typedef void Y(int);
void y( int a ) {
  cout << "y() " << a << endl;
}

Y& oy = y;
Y* yp = &oy;
```

Now both `oy(1)` and `yp(1)` are legal, because function pointers are implicitly dereferenced when called.